# Android Smart way to deal json data offline while json data is too large

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley, offline

Scenario:

I have an large amount of json data which is I'm parsing through the volley now the my question is for offline dealing with data which is the best option use cache ,preference or make an sqlite for this? also one thing is sync data when internet is available

I'm confused for use the way i know answer is opinion based but its not a spam i want to know which is the best way to do this

Thanks advance!

Comment: *use cache or make an sqlite for this?* cache? How

Comment: i'm asking for volley cache

Comment: How large are we talking exactly? How many nodes does your JSON have?

Comment: may be approx it have a thousands of data related to match score

Comment: Using sharedPref would be bad way, you should either use application's private memory or use sqlite db. Suppose you use app's private memory and for any reason user clears application's data then all your data will be lost, app will need to download json again but you can get rid of this issue using database. But I think db operations will be little slower than operations with app's memory, but the difference will be negligible, won't be more than few micro seconds.

Comment: @apurva thanks for your guide but we can prevent user from clear the app memory than?is it fine to use like i'll store my json object to string in prefrance and use it?

Comment: You **can't** prevent user to clear app data since it's os level stuff. Android has always allowed user to clear the data or uninstall app from cup cake to marshmallow.

Comment: Ok i got your point for clear app data you mean uninstall app actually i tell about manage space

Answer (score 0):

You can store your JSON data using shared preferences.

```
if(Online){
    // Your Volley Code 
    // Store JSON 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
    .putString("theJson",jsonObject.toString()).apply();
} else {
    if(!notFirstRun){
        JsonObject jsonObject = PreferenceManager.
        getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("theJson",""); 
    }
}
```